# AngularJs radio buttons not working

Tags: angularjs

Should be simple - what am I doing incorrectly?

In my controller:

```
$scope.eventShow = {tab: 'stations'};
```

and, in a view:

```
Show:
<span>
  <label>Stations</label>
  <input type="radio" ng-model="eventShow.tab" value="stations" class="check_box" />
</span>
<span>
  <label>Visitors</label>
  <input type="radio"  ng-model="eventShow.tab" value="visitors" class="check_box" />
</span>
```

I want the radio buttons to toggle, when one is clicked, and `$scope.eventShow.tab` to be updated appropriately

Comment: It should work, could you please add plunkr/fiddle here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working correctly for me. what version of angular are you using? I am using this:
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js

or is it possible you do not have ng-controller in the html?

Comment: I am using v1.5.0, so will update, but it is helpful to hear that the code works for you. That might help me narrow it down somehow